# Export Fusionchart to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I would like to export my FusionChart to PDF using iTextSharp. I am able to export to PDF by use of setting the charts exportEnabled = '1', but I want to be able to export the fusionchart from my controller.

I have my entire fusionchart in a str variable and tried the following :

```
public FileStreamResult ExportPDF(int ProjectID)
    {
        string exportData = String.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", getGraphXMLData(ProjectID));//This Gets the chart and stores into string
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            Font headerFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);
            Font rowfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);

            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;

            return File(output, "application/pdf", "ProfileChart_Report.pdf");

            //return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```

I however get an error on this line : `document.Close();`

The error im getting is :

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in iTextSharp.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The document has no pages.
```

Below is the data in the `exportData` field:

```
<html>
<body>
<chart caption='Project Test' yaxisname='Elevation' xaxisname='Accumulated Length' xaxismaxvalue='1000' xaxisminvalue='100' yaxismaxvalue='200' xnumberprefix='' ynumberprefix='' showcanvasborder='1' canvasborderthickness='0.5' canvasborderalpha= '50' showXAxisLine= '0' showformbtn= '1' formAction='#' submitdataasxml='1' baseFontColor='#333333' baseFont='Helvetica Neue, Arial' captionFontSize='14' subcaptionFontSize='14' subcaptionFontBold='0' showBorder='0' bgColor='#ffffff' showValues='0' showShadow='0' canvasBgColor='#ffffff' divlineAlpha='100' divlineColor='#999999' divlineThickness='1' divLineIsDashed='1' divLineDashLen='1' divLineGapLen='1' usePlotGradientColor='0' showplotborder='0' showAlternateHGridColor='0' showAlternateVGridColor='0' legendBgAlpha='0' legendBorderAlpha='0' legendShadow='0' legendItemFontSize='10' legendItemFontColor='#666666' toolTipColor='#ffffff' toolTipBorderThickness='0' toolTipBgColor='#000000' toolTipBgAlpha='80' toolTipBorderRadius='2' toolTipPadding = '5' labeldisplay= 'rotate' slantlabels= '1' exportEnabled='1' > <categories verticallinecolor='666666' verticallinethickness='1' alpha='40' anchorsides='0' anchorradius='0'><category label='0' x='0' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='46.17' x='46.17' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='142.98' x='142.98' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='543.88' x='543.88' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='826.58' x='826.58' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='1037.93' x='1037.93' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='1106.1' x='1106.1' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='1338.1' x='1338.1' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='1838.5' x='1838.5' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='1889.37' x='1889.37' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='2538' x='2538' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='2789.04' x='2789.04' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='3154.34' x='3154.34' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='3345.17' x='3345.17' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='4220.75' x='4220.75' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='4671.9' x='4671.9' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='5057.74' x='5057.74' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='5318.51' x='5318.51' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='5576.18' x='5576.18' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='5958.13' x='5958.13' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='6537.92' x='6537.92' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='7282.09' x='7282.09' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='8178.84' x='8178.84' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='8511.22' x='8511.22' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='8989.59' x='8989.59' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='9442.78' x='9442.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='9862.78' x='9862.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='9942.78' x='9942.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='10402.78' x='10402.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='10607.78' x='10607.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='11052.78' x='11052.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='11267.78' x='11267.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='11797.78' x='11797.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='12307.78' x='12307.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='12572.78' x='12572.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='13229.78' x='13229.78' showverticalline='0'/>
<category label='13369.78' x='13369.78' showverticalline='0'/>
</categories>
<dataset  drawline= '1' seriesname= 'Elevation' color= '#0045ff' anchorsides= '0' anchorradius= '0' anchorbgcolor= '#0045ff' anchorbordercolor= '#0045ff'>
<set y='321' x='0'/>
<set y='322' x='46.17'/>
<set y='322.54' x='142.98'/>
<set y='309.12' x='543.88'/>
<set y='292.63' x='826.58'/>
<set y='299.12' x='1037.93'/>
<set y='298.68' x='1106.1'/>
<set y='303.49' x='1338.1'/>
<set y='294.23' x='1838.5'/>
<set y='295.77' x='1889.37'/>
<set y='269.98' x='2538'/>
<set y='274.17' x='2789.04'/>
<set y='261.71' x='3154.34'/>
<set y='267.01' x='3345.17'/>
<set y='243.04' x='4220.75'/>
<set y='247.05' x='4671.9'/>
<set y='250.81' x='5057.74'/>
<set y='246.4' x='5318.51'/>
<set y='249.62' x='5576.18'/>
<set y='238.03' x='5958.13'/>
<set y='253.08' x='6537.92'/>
<set y='235.53' x='7282.09'/>
<set y='173.53' x='8178.84'/>
<set y='189.91' x='8511.22'/>
<set y='224.23' x='8989.59'/>
<set y='250' x='9442.78'/>
<set y='250' x='9862.78'/>
<set y='253.45' x='9942.78'/>
<set y='240' x='10402.78'/>
<set y='235' x='10607.78'/>
<set y='210' x='11052.78'/>
<set y='210' x='11267.78'/>
<set y='195' x='11797.78'/>
<set y='170' x='12307.78'/>
<set y='160' x='12572.78'/>
<set y='150' x='13229.78'/>
<set y='141.36' x='13369.78'/>
</dataset>
<dataset  drawline= '1' seriesname= 'HGL' color= '#198500' anchorsides= '0' anchorradius= '0' anchorbgcolor= '#198500' anchorbordercolor= '#198500'>
<set y='321' x='0'/>
<set y='320.87' x='46.17'/>
<set y='320.59' x='142.98'/>
<set y='319.46' x='543.88'/>
<set y='318.66' x='826.58'/>
<set y='318.06' x='1037.93'/>
<set y='317.87' x='1106.1'/>
<set y='317.22' x='1338.1'/>
<set y='315.81' x='1838.5'/>
<set y='315.67' x='1889.37'/>
<set y='313.84' x='2538'/>
<set y='313.1' x='2789.04'/>
<set y='312.02' x='3154.34'/>
<set y='311.38' x='3345.17'/>
<set y='308.46' x='4220.75'/>
<set y='306.96' x='4671.9'/>
<set y='305.68' x='5057.74'/>
<set y='304.81' x='5318.51'/>
<set y='303.95' x='5576.18'/>
<set y='302.68' x='5958.13'/>
<set y='300.75' x='6537.92'/>
<set y='298.27' x='7282.09'/>
<set y='294.88' x='8178.84'/>
<set y='293.39' x='8511.22'/>
<set y='291.25' x='8989.59'/>
<set y='285.78' x='9442.78'/>
<set y='281.31' x='9862.78'/>
<set y='280.46' x='9942.78'/>
<set y='275.55' x='10402.78'/>
<set y='273.37' x='10607.78'/>
<set y='256.15' x='11052.78'/>
<set y='247.84' x='11267.78'/>
<set y='227.36' x='11797.78'/>
<set y='204.03' x='12307.78'/>
<set y='191.92' x='12572.78'/>
<set y='156.49' x='13229.78'/>
<set y='148.94' x='13369.78'/>
</dataset>
<dataset  drawline= '0' seriesname= 'Peak' color= '#ff0000' anchorsides= '3' anchorradius= '5' anchorbgcolor= '#ff0000' anchorbordercolor= '#ff0000'>
<set y='321' x='0'/>
<set y='322.54' x='142.98'/>
<set y='299.12' x='1037.93'/>
<set y='303.49' x='1338.1'/>
<set y='295.77' x='1889.37'/>
<set y='274.17' x='2789.04'/>
<set y='267.01' x='3345.17'/>
<set y='250.81' x='5057.74'/>
<set y='249.62' x='5576.18'/>
<set y='253.08' x='6537.92'/>
<set y='253.45' x='9942.78'/>
<set y='141.36' x='13369.78'/>
</dataset>
<dataset  drawline= '0' seriesname= 'Valve - Change' color= '#198500' anchorsides= '4' anchorradius= '5' anchorbgcolor= '#198500' anchorbordercolor= '#198500'>
<set y='309.12' x='543.88'/>
<set y='235.53' x='7282.09'/>
<set y='235' x='10607.78'/>
<set y='195' x='11797.78'/>
<set y='150' x='13229.78'/>
</dataset>
<dataset  drawline= '0' seriesname= 'Valve suggest - Long Node' color= '#fdff00' anchorsides= '4' anchorradius= '3' anchorbgcolor= '#fdff00' anchorbordercolor= '#fdff00'>
<set y='321' x='0'/>
<set y='309.12' x='543.88'/>
<set y='294.23' x='1838.5'/>
<set y='269.98' x='2538'/>
<set y='261.71' x='3154.34'/>
<set y='243.04' x='4220.75'/>
<set y='247.05' x='4671.9'/>
<set y='250.81' x='5057.74'/>
<set y='238.03' x='5958.13'/>
<set y='253.08' x='6537.92'/>
<set y='235.53' x='7282.09'/>
<set y='173.53' x='8178.84'/>
<set y='189.91' x='8511.22'/>
<set y='224.23' x='8989.59'/>
<set y='250' x='9442.78'/>
<set y='250' x='9862.78'/>
<set y='240' x='10402.78'/>
<set y='210' x='11052.78'/>
<set y='195' x='11797.78'/>
<set y='170' x='12307.78'/>
<set y='150' x='13229.78'/>
</dataset>
</chart>
</body>
</html>
```

I specifically want to do it in iTextSharp as I have other exports that im doing that is also using iTextSharp and ultimately want to combine everything into one PDF.

I would appreciate anyones help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `exportData`? The error you are showing means that iText couldn't find anything in there to turn into PDF commands.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - Sorry, I guess it would have helped to have added that... I have added it to my post now.

Comment: @AxleWack Are `chart` and `category` really valid HTML? I do not think so. (Or is my HTML knowledge that outdated?)... Googl'ing for *FusionChart* I found http://www.fusioncharts.com/ and that page announces "JavaScript charts" as its topic. iText(Sharp)'s `XmlWorker` works on static HTML or XML but does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: I dont know - Im sure I wouldnt have asked the question If I did...? And as I mentioned, I specifically want to do it using iTextSharp, otherwise I wouldnt have said so. If you are able to help, I would greatly appreciate it, otherwise, please dont comment to those who are actually in need of help. Thanks!

Comment: @AxleWack, the short answer is that iText doesn't have a direct parser for your data. You have a data format that is proprietary to your charting program. Without a schema definition the nodes have no context or meaning. Without that, the `<set>` node means the same as the `<cheeseBurger>` node. As mkl pointed out, your program uses JS to render but iText doesn't ship with a JS interpreter. That said, with a little bit of work you can write an XML parser that walks your nodes and turns them into PDF commands. However, this is probably outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks, I appreciate the more details reply. Is there any other way if getting the FusionChart to be passed to the iText ? Perhaps creating an image of the FusionChart and passing to the iText ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a lot about FusionCharts. As far as I can tell they are a JavaScript-only solution and do not support creating images directly. However, there are programs that can interpret JS and create images for you. See this [post here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/) for two possible solutions that might work for you. They show PHP code but I think both projects work in .Net, too.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas. I will look into it and let you know if I am able to get it working. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: So ive been able to export the FusionChart in 2 different ways. 1. setting the exportenabled = '1'  which enabled a button that allows the chart to be exported in many different ways(png, jpg, pdf etc.) and 2. By writing a small javascript function which is run from the nav bar. However, NONE of the annotations(images) or background image are displayed on the exported file... why would this be ? Is it another setting I need to enable ?